# OpenCSManager failed 1722, the RPC server is unavailable

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, rpc

I have configured CI/CD build configuration for one of the repository, using build/release I am trying to create a service in on-premise machine (domain joined) using powershell script but I am always getting an exception that OpenCSManager failed 1722, the RPC server is unavailable

CI/CD logs:

Deployment started for machine: 'servername.domain.com:5986'

[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722

The RPC server is unavailable.

I have already configured the RPC service with automatic option in the target machine's services msc,

Enabled firewall for port 5986 and created https lisnter and enabled remote sharing with printer etc.

Even i have followed the steps which have been described in the article.but nothing seems working..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=vsts

Answer (score 0):

I have re-installed VSTS agent after un-installing the old agent.